# std::vector<Class *> does not get copy constructed correctly

Tags: c++, c++11, std, stdvector

I have a Class particle like this,

```
class Particle
{
public:
    std::vector<Particle*> getNbh () const;
    void setNbh (const std::vector<Particle*>&);
private:
    std::vector<Particle*> nbh_;
};
```

and the function `Particle::setNbh(const std::vector<Particle*>&)` is implemented,

```
void Particle::setNbh (const std::vector<Particle*>& nbh)
{
    nbh_ = nbh;
}
```

then there is a non-member function `updateNeighbors (std::vector<Particle>& particles, double cutoff)`

```
void updateNeighbors (std::vector<Particle>& particles, double cutoff)
{
    for (auto particle : particles)
    {
        auto nbh = std::vector<Particle*>();
        for (auto other : particles)
            if (&particle != &other 
                && norm(particle.getPosition() - other.getPosition()) < cutoff)
                nbh.push_back(&other);
        particle.setNbh(nbh);
    }
}
```

The thing is that when I update the neighbors with this function, the `nbh_` member does not get updated correctly, I test it printing the size of `getNbh()` for each particle.

Which is the correct way of copy constructing `std::vector<Particle*>` so I can get the desired behavior?

Comment: The whole implementation [here](http://dpaste.org/voLsx/)

Comment: nbh_ is vector of pointers to Particle and updateNeighbors takes vector of Particle by value. How will it work? How does the updateNeighbors has access to nbh_?

Comment: I takes it as references, it's intended to update the nbh_ to each particle in a vector of Particle

Comment: Is there copy constructor and copy assignment operator in Particle?

Comment: @Abhijit Kadam the default is left, i.e. Particle has not a custom copy constructor

Comment: Didnt look into the entire code, but probably this might help: `for (auto& particle : particles)`

Comment: @Thrustmaster thanks, that works, publish it as an answer, the thing was simple, particle an other in the ranged for loops where created as value not as reference, lesson learned thanks a lot.

Comment: Is `updateNeighbors` called with particles with local scope. Then because of `nbh.push_back(&other)` `nbh`will have dangling pointers to nothing once the function `updateNeighbors` returns

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace `for ( auto` with `for ( auto&&` in both of your loops.

You are creating a local copy of each `Particle` from your `particles` vector, and I strongly expect you don't intend to.

`auto&&` uses `&&` in a type deduction context, which means that `auto&&` is either an rvalue reference, a `const` reference, or a normal reference, depending on what the variable is initialized by.  It is a decent "default" way to iterate over containers when you just don't want to think about it.

Comment: Who deserves the accepted answer you or @Thrustmaster?, I see your answer better explained but he commented with a working answer first.

Comment: @OscarDavidArbeláez give it to Thrust :)

Comment: @Yakk Haha, its just fine, really! The accepted answer should be precise and elaborate on explanation (like yours), regardless of who came first. :)

Answer (score 5):

In

```
particle.setNbh(nbh);
```

You are actually setting `nbh(..)` on a "copy" of the element while iterating. You should actually be using references while iterating if you are planning on modifying them. Use:

```
for (auto& particle : particles)
```